# The file is damage and can not be opened in Itextsharp pdf creation

Tags: pdf, itext

I am sorry if this not really a very constructive question but believe me issue is hitting me hard.Now here is the description of the situation.
I want to create a pdf page divided equally into two parts .I googled and got to know that `ColumnText` can be used to do the same with the latest .dll of the itexthsarp.

So i got the code like this..

```
    public static void paraPDF()
    {
        string imagepath = "D:\\pdf\\Hello.pdf";
        Document doc = new Document();
        try
        {
            string TEXT = "This is some long paragraph that will be added over and over again to prove a point.";
            Rectangle[] COLUMNS = { new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, 806), new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, 806) };
            PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer2.DirectContent;
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
            int side_of_the_page = 0;
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
            int paragraphs = 0;
            while (paragraphs < 30)
            {
                ct.AddElement(new Paragraph(String.Format("Paragraph %s: %s", ++paragraphs, TEXT)));
                while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
                {
                    if (side_of_the_page == 0)
                    {
                        side_of_the_page = 1;
                        canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
                        canvas.LineTo(297.5f, 806);
                        canvas.Stroke();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        side_of_the_page = 0;
                        doc.NewPage();
                    }
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);

                }
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
        catch { 


        }
    }
}
```

On running above method,pdf file is getting created with some data inside as size is not zero kb but i am not able to open because i am getting error as..`The file is damage and can not be opened in Itextsharp pdf creation`

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file end with %%EOF when you open it in a text editor? You are doing something dangerous in your code snippet: you have a "catch" clause that "eats exceptions" and you have `doc.close()` inside that the "try" clause. Nobody will be able to help you if you don't say which exception is thrown.

Comment: Actually, you have `doc.close()` inside a while loop. This can't be right. Allow me to update your question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Ok i putted doc.close() outside the while and now i am able to open the file ..but i am not getting data in columntext form which divides the page into two half..

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am getting only `Paragraph %s: %s` inside the created pdf

Comment: Please read my answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Ok Sir .I have changed doc.close() and string.Format.Now again the title issue that The file is damage and can not be opened error

Comment: But you're still not telling us which exception you are ignoring in the catch clause. **Please understand that you are withholding important information from those spending time trying to answer your question.**

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am getting `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.` error in the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two problems:

1. You have put `doc.close()` at the wrong position. I've fixed this in your question. This solves your "The file is damaged" problem, revealing a second problem concerning String formatting.
2. You are using Java syntax in C#, as a result, the String formatting is all wrong.

In Java, you can do:

```
String.format("Paragraph %s: %s", ++paragraphs, TEXT)
```

In C#, you need to do:

```
String.Format("Paragraph {0}: {1}", ++paragraphs, TEXT)
```

**Disclaimer:** I don't know C#. I've never written a C# program. I've just Googled for the answer and this is what I found. If it's not correct, I Google some more.

Comment: Ok Sir .I have changed doc.close() and string.Format.Now again the title issue that The file is damage and can not be opened error

Comment: Can you share the PDF. Does it end with %%EOF? Also: how did you know that the String was shown as `Paragraph %s: %s` if you couldn't open the file?

Comment: %PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
 this is the pdf content from the notepad

Comment: That is a PDF header that is written at the moment you invoke `doc.Open()`. If nothing else is written, you encountered an exception that prevented any other data to be added. You are obstructing the people trying to help you by not disclosing the nature of that exception. Hence, it is assumed that you're not really interested in the answer to your problem. If that assumption is wrong, please comply and explain which exception is thrown.

Comment: I am getting Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. error in the catch

Comment: Note that upon reviewing my answer, I noticed a typo. It goes without saying that `{2}` should have been `{1}`. There are only two extra parameters, so using `{2}` would throw the equivalent of an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Note that that wasn't an iTextSharp problem. It was a simple C# String formatting problem. The exception told you exactly what was wrong.

Comment: Yet many people hate me for giving advice: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258163/1622493